# Why is there a difference between the procedural track heading and final approach course at Fort Hood (KGRK)?

Tags: non-precision-approach

Looking at the NDB RWY 15 into Fort Hood/Killeen, why is the procedural track from OKEST showing a heading of 151 degrees when the final approach course heading is 150 degrees. Is that simply a typo? The best answer I can come up is that from OKEST to the LOM is 6.3NM on a heading of 151 degrees. Is the 151 heading to GRK VOR or to the LOM using the NDB? Any thoughts?[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's really only confusing because they are within one degree of each other, but this actually happens quite a bit with feeder routes.

#### The 151 Degree Course NW of STARN

The 151 degree course (and the OKEST intersection) is only used if you are using AGJ as the Initial Approach Fix (IAF). This is the course that you would fly from OKEST towards the GRK VOR (on the GRK 331 degree radial) in order to get to STARN.  After reaching STARN, you would fly the 150 degree bearing outbound from STARN and the rest of the approach using STARN to navigate.

#### The 150 Degree Bearing NW of STARN

If you were to use STARN as the IAF instead of AGJ, you would fly the procedure turn on the 150 degree bearing from it in order to get yourself established on the correct inbound course to fly the rest of the approach.  In this case, you would never use GRK at all.

Comment: As a side note, a 1° shift makes very little difference in a non-precision approach. At 5 miles, 1° corresponds to about 500 feet track offset; at 10 miles, 1,000 feet. You should still always fly the charted procedure, as accurately as possible, but if you get it wrong by 1° nobody is going to notice (and you'll still be *well* within the protected regions of the approach).

Comment: Would it also be depicted like this if we were right at a rounding boundary for magnetic variation?

Comment: @falstro No, because the navaid courses/radials are all relative to each other so that wouldn't matter.  In this case though, it's just two different navaids that aren't perfectly aligned.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thank you for clearing this up!